# Subset Data Frame by String AND Number, not Either Or

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, subset

I'm wondering how to subset (or filter) a data frame by two columns (one is string, one is number) including only results where both conditions are met, not one or the other.

If I use the & operator, it returns data where either condition is met.

```
data(iris)

foo <- iris[which(iris$Petal.Length > 1.2 & iris$Species != "setosa"),]
```

This returns only versicolor and virginica results above 1.2, rather than the setosa results that are above 1.2 as well. **How would I go about getting all results where the Petal Length is above 1.2 and if it is below 1.2 and is setosa it is removed?**

I'm fine using `sqldf` or `dplyr` if that is the route you suggest going. Any other alternatives are welcome, as well.

Comment: Not sure I understand your logic correclty.  Wouldn't `as.data.table(iris)[Petal.Length > 1.2]` gives the expected output

Comment: @akrun Your submitted answers were what I was looking for. I am fine with returning setosa results > 1.2 Petal Length, so that requires its own statement. In this data frame, the other two variables have no values below 1.2, but if they did I would want them included regardless. That's why your simple comment answer would not work. If there was a versicolor at 0.5 Petal Length, it would be incorrectly excluded.

Comment: Oh, ok, I got confused by the data iris with only three Species.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(iris)[Species == "setosa" & Petal.Length> 1.2| 
                         Species != "setosa" & Petal.Length > 1.2]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
iris %>%
     filter(Species == "setosa" & Petal.Length > 1.2 |
             Species != "setosa" & Petal.Length > 1.2)
```

Comment: This was one of those obvious answers that I couldn't think of in the moment. Thanks for your answer! Do you have a personal preference for one method over the other and reasoning why?

Comment: @medavis6  I like both packages, but when I work on projects, I usually go with `data.table` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
require(dplyr)
foo <- filter(iris,Petal.Length > 1.2 & Species != "setosa")
```

This will return all observations where the petal length is > 1.2 and the Species is not Setosa

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I apologize if I was being unclear, but your answer would remove all setosa answers from the resulting data frame. I want to include ALL versicolor & virginica answers, along with any setosa results where Petal Length is > 1.2.

Comment: I see now - looks like akrun has you covered. All the best!